# Visual Studio Solution freezes when I try to compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

I have no idea how to even approach debugging this issue.  I have a solution with four projects in it and all of a sudden it has stopped functioning properly.

When I open the solution and click on anything, it freezes up and it says that **'Visual Studio is busy waiting for an internal operation to complete"**.  It gives the same message when I try to build the project, although it never actually opens the file or builds - I have to end the process in order to escape.

Comment: What did you change from previous builds when this started occuring? It is probably no coincidence that it happened all of a sudden.

Comment: Attach another instance of VS to the crashing process. This is especially useful when VS tries to execute code on the fly (outside of a compile, such as when evaluating a UI component)

Comment: Did you try restarting the computer?  Visual Studio may lock up if another instance is trying to do something (they seem to share a worker thread).  Restarting will terminate all programs and let you start over.

Comment: I tried restarting the computer, and I have also tried running the code on multiple other computers.  I have also tried doing the debugging with another instance of visual studio but it doesn't seem to be giving me any useful information.  I am racking my brain trying to figure out what I could have changed to cause this but I didn't really do anything special (that I can figure out)

Comment: If the answers below do not work then try rebuilding the project file by file, till it stops working.  If you are using a source control (like TFS) you could also go back till you find a version which runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To troubleshoot this you could start visual studio in safemode, by running: devenv.exe /SafeMode. It loads only default settings and services. If it works then the culprit is something like an extension or a third party package.

You can also start Visual Studio with logging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

For a list of other command line switches you can use, like /ResetSettings, you can follow this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried a bunch of different things and this is the only one that worked - I'm not sure what caused the issue but safe mode allowed me to load the solution, fix any compile problems and compile - and now it seems to be working!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should install the [Visual Studio 2010 Diagnostic Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4), to try and capture some data that can be sent to MS for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is opening VS, opening a working project and then opening the one that is experiencing the problem. Everything works fine after that.